# PHP: Match line against array of regexes

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a quick PHP parser here and was wondering instead of writing

```
foreach($array as $line) {
  if(preg_match($regex1, ..) {

  } 
  elseif(preg_match($regex2, ..) {

  }
}
```

Is there possible to match against an array of regexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($text_array as $line){
    foreach($regex_array as $regex{
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the best way to do it? =)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is a PHP Perl-style regular expression method that will do this. `preg_replace` and `preg_filter` both accept an array of expressions but they perform replacement in addition to matching.

Comment: What strikes you from this approach as too complex? :)